# ssh is taking too much time to connect/not connecting

Tags: networking, server, ssh, nagios3

When I am trying to login to a nagios server it is giving trouble to all the users at a time to connect. Either taking too much time to connect or not at all connecting.

This is what is happening while trying to connect.

```
bbnladmin@bbnladmin~$ ssh kiran@<ip address> -p714 -vvvv

OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0  
debug1: Connecting to <ip address> [ip address] port 714.
```

This stops at this point an doesn't go forth.

Please help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a firewall issue. Check if the firewall in the nagios server is blocking the connections. Also, check the /etc/hosts file in the nagios server and see if there are any interesting entries, like host vice ACLs

Comment: It wasnt actually necessary. The system started working post a routing change. There could be a routing issue also possible right?

Answer (score 0):

You did read `man ssh`, which says, in  part:

```
SYNOPSIS
     ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
         [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
         [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
         [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
         [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
         [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
         [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
         [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

Comparing this to the command you used, we find that you told `ssh` to:

```
ssh kiran@<ip address>
```

using its default options, connect to `<ip address>` as user `kiran`, then execute the "command"

```
-p714 -vvvv
```

which probably is not what you want.

Options should be put **before** the `user@hostname` part, .e.g.:

```
ssh -p 714 -vvvv kiran@<ip address>
```

Comment: No, `ssh` sees the `-vvvv` as options just fine (which is can be seen by the verbose log present in the question). You can test: try `ssh  <som-system> -vvvv echo foo` on some system you have SSH access to.

Comment: Thanks alot for the responses. It was actually a networking related issue i seems. Re-configuring the switch ports had fixed the problem.